# Is there any way to incorporate collisions in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Just wondering if there was any easy way to create collision events on a Tkinter canvas, as I am attempting to create a game in Tkinter.

I have seen some complex ways, but I was wondering if there was a simple solution.

I have been using Tkinter much longer than I have been using pygame, so I would prefer to stick to Tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own with tkinter's [bbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method) to check if the collisions happen or to make your desired effect. you can use other great words in that link to help you on get your collision engine be nice and running.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in collision detection, other than the [find_overlapping](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method) and [find_enclosed](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_enclosed-method) methods of the canvas which can find objects that overlap or are enclosed by a rectangular region (and the fact that you can get the rectangular bounding box of any object).